# MVC4: Retrieving a related list with Entity and casting it as List<> or IEnum<> for View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This a simple project where users can search for job postings by area of expertise. The relationship between Areas and Postings are Many-to-many. I seem to be able to get to the very last part of retrieving the correctly filtered list, but getting back into the view model keeps giving me different errors:

ViewModel:

```
    public class AreaOfertasViewModel
{
    public Oferta UnaOferta { get; set; }
    public SelectList AreasTrabajo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Oferta> Ofertas { get; set; }
    public int idArea { get; set; }

    public AreaOfertasViewModel()
    {
        this.UnaOferta = UnaOferta;
        this.Ofertas = new List<Oferta>();
        cargarAreas();
    }

    private void cargarAreas()
    {
        PostulaOfertaContext db = new PostulaOfertaContext();
        this.AreasTrabajo = new SelectList(db.Areas, "areaId", "Area");
    }
}
```

}

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult SearchXArea()
    {
        return View(new AreaOfertasViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchXArea(AreaOfertasViewModel aovm)
    {
        int id = aovm.idArea;
        PostulaOfertaContext db = new PostulaOfertaContext();
        var area = db.Areas.Where(c => c.areaId == id);
        var ofertas = from c in db.Ofertas.Where(r => r.AreaTrabajo == area)
                      select c;
        aovm.Ofertas = (IEnumerable<Oferta>)ofertas.ToList();
        return View(aovm);
    }
```

The line giving me issues is
aovm.Ofertas = (IEnumerable)ofertas.ToList();

I've tried List<> for Ofertas, and I've tried leaving it as .ToList() without casting, and casting it as different things, but it gives me errors about not being able to cast it, and "Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported."

What's the solution here?

Model for AreaTrabajo:

```
    public class AreaTrabajo
{
    [Key]
    public int areaId { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Oferta> oferta { get; set; }
}
```

Model for Oferta:

```
    public class Oferta
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Vencimiento { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Cargo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int HorarioComienzo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int HorarioFin { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DescripcionTareas { get; set; }
    public int Remuneracion { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RangoEdadMin { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RangoEdadMax { get; set; }
    public string TipoFormacion { get; set; }
    public string Idiomas { get; set; }
    public string Competencias { get; set; }
    public string OtrosEstudios { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AreaTrabajo> AreaTrabajo { get; set; } 
    public virtual TipoContrato TipoContrato { get; set; }          
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Postulante> Postulantes { get; set; }
}
```

**Answer**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchXArea(AreaOfertasViewModel aovm)
    {
        int id = aovm.idArea;
        PostulaOfertaContext db = new PostulaOfertaContext();
        var area = db.Areas.Where(c => c.areaId == id).FirstOrDefault();

        var ofertas = db.Ofertas.Where(s => s.AreaTrabajo.All(e => e.areaId == area.areaId)).ToList();
        aovm.Ofertas = ofertas;
        return View(aovm);
    }
```

Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I needed to filter out from the many-to-many relationship, and this solved it.

Comment: `var  area` is `IEnumerable<Area>` so `.Where(r => r.AreaTrabajo == area)` could not work. You need to show the data models, but best guess is you need `var area = db.Areas.Where(c => c.areaId == id).FirstOrDefault()` to return a single object. The it may need to be `var ofertas = from c in db.Ofertas.Where(r => r.AreaTrabajo == area.SomeProperty)`

Comment: There's only an IEnumerable<Oferta>. I do get a list back, but the conversion from the entity query result into a List<Oferta> or IEnumerable<Oferta> gives me errors.

Comment: `var area = db.Areas.Where(c => c.areaId == id);` is not `IEnumerable<Oferta>`! What does `var ofertas` return? (And get rid of that `cargarAreas();` line inside your view model constructor - that belongs in the controller - not the model!)

Comment: I see. Sorry.. Learning MVC. The problem I have on var ofertas = from c in db.Ofertas.Where(r => r.AreaTrabajo == area.SomeProperty) is that r.AreaTrabajo is a list of AreaTrabajos, and I have no idea how to use EF to return a query that only matches one ID in that model's List<> of them. r.AreaTrabajo, for obvious reasons, has no properties, so I was trying to compare one object to another this whole time. How would I do this in a single query?

Comment: You need to show your models (for `Area` and `Oferta` and `AreaTrabajo`)

Comment: Added. There is no model for "Area". It's just the name of the AreaTrabajo in that model.

Comment: So does `var area = db.Areas` return `IEnumerable<AreaTrabajo>`? (sorry hard to understand this because it not English names)

Comment: It returns a single AreaTrabajo with FirstOrDefault now.

Comment: So therefore `var ofertas = area.oferta;` will be `IEnumerable<Oferta>`

Comment: Yes, it should be. But because oferta is many-to-many with AreaTrabajo, the AreaTrabajo in Oferta is a list of Areas and have no properties to access. That;s my main issue here. How do I access that list?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because the actual sql is executed when you call tolist(). The error is in your sql because you are comparing AreaTrabago to a list.

Comment: IEnumerable is lazy loaded and the sql is not executed until it is used

Comment: I tried doing ToList() in the query itself, surrounding the query in paratheses. It still gives Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Comment: Change to: var area = db.Areas.FirstOrDefault(c => c.areaId == id);

Comment: This won't work you are querying for a list of areas then querying for ofertas that contain a select list of these areas. You can only compare a primitive type: string, int, bool. You need to store a foreign key of the areaid inside ofertas.

Comment: This seems to be the big issue. I'm trying to figure out how to get a foreign key from a many to many relationship. Entity....

Comment: Sorry I'm on a phone I can't type the class for you but what I would do is create a bookauthors class with a primary key Id,  bookid, book, authorid, author. Add this class to your context and recreate your database.

Comment: Your looking for AreaTrabagos that contain a list of areas. Your list of areas all contain a single areaid. Store this areaid in your AreaTrabagos

Comment: It is in there, but because I return a List<> of them in the query, that's inaccessible. (I added the models to my OP)

Comment: Chanhe to: var area = db.Areas.Include ("Oferta").Where(c => c.areaId == id);

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchXArea(AreaOfertasViewModel aovm)
    {
        int id = aovm.idArea;
        PostulaOfertaContext db = new PostulaOfertaContext();
        var area = db.Areas.Where(c => c.areaId == id).FirstOrDefault();

        var ofertas = db.Ofertas.Where(s => s.AreaTrabajo.All(e => e.areaId == area.areaId)).ToList();
        aovm.Ofertas = ofertas;
        return View(aovm);
    }
```

Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I couldn't get the many-to-many relationship, and this solved the filtering problem perfectly.